# Creating New Component throws error:PriorityQueue is not a constructor

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I got a weird error while creating new component using Angular CLI,when I used `ng g c navbar` it throws error:

```
 core_1.PriorityQueue is not a constructor
TypeError: core_1.PriorityQueue is not a constructor
    at new TaskScheduler (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/task.js:20:23)
    at SchematicEngine.createContext (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:81:31)
    at SchematicImpl.call (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/schematic.js:35:38)
    at Promise (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/schematic-run.js:73:23)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.run (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/schematic-run.js:72:16)
    at Class.run (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:161:33)
    at resolve (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:261:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.validateAndRun (/home/praveen/Desktop/Angular_Projects/a2website/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:240:12)
```

Can anyone help me?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your package.json you will see:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@angular-devkit/core": "OLD VERSION",  <----- once you run the command this will update
    ...
 }
```

Command to run the update:

```
npm i -D @angular-devkit/core@latest
```

Comment: and `npm install @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.45 -D`

Comment: Thanks everyone, one more solution can be downgrading angular cli to 1.5.0 globally.`npm remove -g @angular/cli` and then
`npm install -g @angular/cli@1.5.0`.It works for project using Angular 4.

Answer (score 2):

Update your angular cli or make sure you are running the latest version of angular cli.

To install the latest version of angular cli use the command:

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`